# Programs have disappeared from Windows 7 Start Menu

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, start-menu

I am running (and love) Windows 7 RC1 on my machine.

In the first real weird thing I have seen in Windows 7 -- all of my programs have disappeared from the start menu.  So if I click the start button and click all programs it shows an empty white column where it normally would show the program groups or shortcuts to my programs.  No programs or shortcuts show up at all.

Any ideas on how to get them back?

Seth

Comment: If you browse to c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs do you see any icons there?

Comment: Or just right-click on All Program and choose Open All users...

Comment: This has probably been fixed in the RTM, but you should submit it to Connect anyway just in case.

Comment: Hello,
squillman.  Yes...all my folders and shortcuts are at the path you mentioned.  Thanks...even if can't get them to reappear I will at least know where they are now.  Open All users takes me to the Start Menu folder but same path as in other post.  Post your comment as an answer.  

mrdenny...How do I submit the issue to Connect?

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete some shortcut from the c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs to get total programs in that folder are less than 70 because more than 70 shortcut in there that what happen to me which it just display nothing but I already fix mine with this way.

Comment: Yep ... that was it.  I got the answer from superuser.com
Seth

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and in my case it was because I had the icons of the Start Menu set to "hidden" (don't know if in the English Windows it's as "hidden", I use a portuguese version of Windows 7). I right-clicked the "All programs" menu and selected "Open All Users" like squillman did, it opened the folder /programdata/microsoft/windows/start menu. In the "start menu" folder properties (which I accessed by right-clicking the folder, as usual), I unticked the "hidden" option, ande evrything back to normal. Don't know if yours is the same problem, but it worked for me. I probably caused this by setting the entire "windows" folder to be "hidden", so... Good luck!